# Component Re-rendering issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-typescript

I am working on the project in React Typescript.
I have created hierarchy of components as per requirement.
In one scenario I have to pass data from child component to parent component and I am passing function as props and it works.

Issue :

- When passing data to parent component child component gets re-render it looks like. Mean to say Dropdown selection is get reset and tree control expanded nodes get collapsed and set to the position as first time rendered.

I have used useState,useEffects hooks.
I have also tried React.memo as a part of my search on internet.

What I need :

- I want to pass data to parent component from child without re-render the child component as there is no change in the props of child component.

Comment: The reason is most likely that your child components do not have an open/close state and the rest, so the child component is installed with the initial values

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

Add `useCallback` hook to memoize your function which lift data to `<Parent />`.

Then use `React.memo` for `<Child />` to control prop changes and avoid unwanted re-renders.

I prepare an example for you [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-bhaskara-ey9e6u?file=/src/App.js).

UPD. I have uploaded an example, you can copy it and see how it works!

Here is `Child` component:

```
const Child = ({ onChange }) => {
   console.log("Child re-render");

  return (
        <div className="App">
         <h1>Child</h1>
         <button onClick={() => onChange(Math.random())}>
          Lift value to Parant
         </button>
        </div>
    );
  };

const areEqual = ({ onChange: prevOnChange }, { onChange }) => {
   return prevOnChange === onChange; // if true => this will avoid render
}

export default React.memo(Child, areEqual);
```

And the `Parent`:

```
consn App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const onChange = useCallback((value) => setValue(String(value)), []);

  console.log("Parant re-render");

 return (
       <div className="App">
         <h1>Parent</h1>
         <div>Value is: {value}</div>
         <Child onChange={onChange} />
       </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you include your code-snippet here as well? Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript/HTML/CSS. (See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Help others reproduce the problem)